# Proof for odd powers of sin: $\int(\sin x)^{2n+1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n+1}\,dx=\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{2j}{2j + 1}$ for odd powers of sin.

I have been able to reduce this to: $\frac{2n}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n-1}\,dx$

and I am not quite sure how to integrate $(\sin x)^{2n-1}$.

Would integration by parts be enough to solve this? If so, then how?
My implementation was to set $u = (\sin x)^{2n-1}$ and $dv = dx$ but I get a greater mess when I integrate by parts.

Comment: I am surprised that there are two answers, one of which has already been accepted, and no one has addressed that the identity the OP is asking about is false.  For instance, as functions of $n$ the left hand side is decreasing and converges to $0$ and the right hand side is increasing and converges to $1$. (Or check that when $n = 2$ the left hand side is $\frac{8}{15}$ and the right hand side is $\frac{4}{5}$.)

Comment: Yeah, OP needs a product symbol on the right hand side. Believe s/he wants $\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{2j}{2j + 1}$. This follows recursively from what s/he wrote on the second line. -- Todd Trimble.

Comment: @user43208: I agree that both methods can be used to give the correct identity, rather than the one that the OP orginally asked for.  It just seemed worth commenting upon that the question was false as stated.

Comment: I fixed the identity

Comment: @PeteL.Clark A friendly "of course!" to both of your sentences in your last comment. Best regards, Todd.

Comment: See: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100702210327AAPH9lg

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You do not have to be surprised! I gave him a very good hint and I did not work out the problem. That's why he corrected his question after that if you notice.

Comment: @Mhenni I doubt your answer was the proximate cause: he corrected seconds after Pete and I made comments below his post. (If I were you, I wouldn't pat myself on the back too much about the hint, by the way.)

Comment: @user43208: My answer is a very good hint! It exposed him to a very powerful tool. By the way, I gave the hint in the first minutes.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: it is indeed good to remark on the connection with Beta integrals. But it's not particularly a time-saving observation, since OP already had all that s/he needed without this hint, and there is a real question whether OP even got the hint. This is my last comment on the matter. You are of course entitled to your own opinion about how wonderful your hint is.

Comment: @user43208: Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that you've already solved most of the problem yourself: your integration by parts is all the calculus you need to do.

You say "I am not quite sure how to integrate $\int (\sin x)^{2n-1}$."  So what I think you are missing is the idea that you can integrate by parts *repeatedly*, reducing the exponent by $2$ each time, until you get down to $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x dx = 1$.  (Calling the power "$2n-1$" does not make for a truly different integral than if the power is called "$2n+1$".)  This concept generally goes under the name [reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae): see the linked wikipedia article for an introduction to how that works.

To get a sense of what's going on, I would recommend that you take a particular value of $n$ and repeatedly integrate by parts and see what you get.  E.g. if $n = 2$ then

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin x)^5 dx = \left(\frac{2(2)}{2(2)+1}\right) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin x)^3 dx = \left(\frac{2(2)}{2(2)+1}\right) \left(\frac{2(1)}{2(1)+1)} \right) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin x) dx = \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{8}{15}$.

If you do this for a few values of $n$ you will see that you are getting a product of certain fractions which is exactly equal to what you want.  (And it helps a lot to have the right hand side written down correctly!  Hence my comments above.)

You can also think of this in terms of finding an explicit formula for a recursively defined sequence if you want...but if you were comfortable with thinking about it that way I think you wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.

By some cosmic coincidence, I talked about reduction formulas in my calculus class yesterday.  A very similar reduction formula leads to an interesting formula of Wallis giving an expression for $\pi$: [see here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Wallis.pdf) if you like.

Comment: Ah great, you took care of it! Also very amused I missed the originally wrong statement.

Answer (score 1):

PS. You can do this by integration by parts if you really, really want. Extract a $\sin^2 x$, turn it into $(1-\cos^2 x)$, and you get (if we let $I_{k} = \int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^k dx$)

$I_{2n+1} = I_{2n-1} - \int_0^{\pi/2} [\sin^{2n-1}(x) \cos (x)] \cos x$.

Use integration by parts now ($u=\cos x$). You actually get a boundary term (evaluates to 0) and a multiple of the original integral, and

$\frac{2n+1}{2n} I_{2n+1} = I_{2n-1}$.

and then some recursive fun.

Comment: This answer seems to say exactly what the OP already knew.  Given that the question was asked, s/he must have had trouble with the recursion: maybe you should say something about that?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Ah I see! Okay then.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is a straightforward application of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: This is a second semester calculus question.  (I did very similar things in my calculus class yesterday, in fact: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Wallis.pdf.)  This answer looks like overkill to me.  Wouldn't you prove the "beta function identity" in question by integrating by parts and solving the recursion?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Maybe it is overkill for you but not for other people!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but now that I've left an answer of my own there's no need to press the point.  Maybe your answer really is better for the OP...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Integration by parts and solving a recurrence relation is a long way to go!

Comment: Are you saying that you have a solution that *does not involve* an integration by parts at any point?  What is it?  (If you say you are using a beta function identity, then you should explain how that identity can be derived without integrating by parts.)  I would say that "solving a recurrence relation" is an unnecessarily complicated description of what is needed here.  It's like saying that writing $\int (\cos x) dx = \sin x + C$ is solving a differential equation.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: It is up to the OP to find out how the beta function was derived. It is good for him to learn this. I gave him a very powerful tool that he can use it for more general integrals and I think you know this.

Comment: *I* am asking whether the beta function identities you are alluding to can be derived without integration by parts (or something more involved).  If it can't, then your comment "Integration by parts...is a long way to go" seems strange.  One can usually answer an undergraduate-level question by giving a reference to a stronger, well-known result, but is this the most useful kind of answer?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: It is your job to look for proofs of beta function!!

Comment: No, that really is not my job.  Especially, it is not my job to divine your intentions.  Your lack of willingness to explain yourself is disappointing.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the down vote for? Your reason for down voting. I think this website is not made to waste people's time and effort.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You think I have much time arguing about a calculus problem!

Comment: About "Your reason for down voting": @Mhenni, Do you actually care for these "reasons"? I wonder because I have seen you asking countless times for them and, when some downvoters did explain their motives and when these were obviously valid, doing nothing about them (in particular evading requests for justifications and leaving blatantly wrong answers on the site forever). So, I had come to the conclusion that you used the whole "What's the down vote for? Your reason for down voting" comment as a kind of empty mantra with no actual meaning. But maybe this is not the case anymore?